# Python: After clicking on an image capture x,y coordinations and close the image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I found some snippet of code which opens an image and prints x,y locations which the user clicks, however it keeps the image open. How can I close the image and terminate the code after the user clicks once? I'm probably missing something simple here. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = tkinter.Tk(className="bla")

size = 500, 500
image = Image.open("sample.png")
image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=image.size[0], height=image.size[1])
canvas.pack()
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(image.size[0]//2, image.size[1]//2, image=image_tk)

def callback(event):
    print ("clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)
    return (0)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to *destroy* the window using the `destroy()` function. Here is an example. Excuse the little tweak that I did considering that I don't have *ImageTk*.

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image

window = tkinter.Tk(className="bla")

size = 500, 500
image = Image.open("sample.png")
image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=image.size[0], height=image.size[1])
canvas.pack()
image_tk = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="sample.png") #Tweak
canvas.create_image(image.size[0]//2, image.size[1]//2, image=image_tk)

def callback(event):
    print ("clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)
    window.destroy()

canvas.bind("", callback)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. How can I return the event.x and event.y values?

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, I didn't get you, considering that you wish to destroy the window immediately. Where do you wish to return those values? Do you have a specific scenario?

Comment: for example how can I create a function around this code: def myFunction() , which returns the (x,y) which the user has clicked on the image. thaaanks

Comment: @Mohammad Well, its still kinda unclear. Maybe you could call myFunction() from the callback and pass the values there, and destroy the window in myFunction() as well. Does this work?